# Is it possible to share a branch to anyone else in the team without committing it in GIT ?

Tags: git

Consider that i am working on a branch and made some changes and need some help from my friend and want to send the branch to him without committing it. 
is it possible? 
Considering that i am working on the main development branch

Comment: No. But you can send him a patch of the work you have already commited but not pushed yet. I think you have to take quick tour on how git really works and get to know the concepts. Your thinking here somehow from the wrong end.

Comment: Could you possibly mean "push" when you say "commit"?

Comment: Consider going on a personal branch and delete it when you have merged back into master.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can send patches to anyone (`git diff >file`).  However, *branches* contain commits (really, they're just a name for *one* commit and its ancestors come along for the ride), so it's meaningless to talk about sharing a branch without having committed anything.